# Unique property with custom adapter Sails.js

Tags: sails.js, adapter, unique, couchbase, nosql

I'm working on a Sails.js application with a Couchbase Server environment, so I've built a custom adapter that manages the actions from the appllication to the DB.

A thing that I can't figure out is how unique properties work. I believed that they work issuing a find request with a custom where clause and establishing whether a result can be returned by the db, but trying to debugging I cannot see any find request in my adapter, and I still can broke uniqueness in properties marked as 'unique'

How can I make the unique property work?